# Number vs new Number internal implementation

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, primitive

I understand that writing

```
var x = Number("7"); // makes a number, a primitive
var y = new Number("7"); // makes a Number object
```

and I'm aware of the usual cautions against option 2, but what is going on behind the scenes? I was under the impression if a function is a constructor, it should not return a value via a return statement: it just sets up its implicit object, this, and returns it.

So how come Number, String, and Boolean constructors are able to return either a primitive or an object? Does the JavaScript engine parse those expressions differently as a special feature in the language? Or can a programmer also "overload" a constructor function to either return a primitive or an object, depending on whether the constructor is called with/without "new"?

Answer (score 2):

Using the constructor the `Number` object will be an object, using the function `Number` instead will return the conversion of an object to its representation as a numeric value.

So, basically within the `Number` object, the function is validating how was called.  This is possible by checking the object `this`.

**Something interesting is coercing the `Number` object to a numeric value as follow:**

```js
var x = Number("7"); // makes a number, a primitive
var y = new Number("7");

console.log(x === +y)
```

**Go and read about the specification**

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the direct reference! It's good to see what is actually written in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with syntax and there's nothing special about those constructors. The `Number()` and other constructors simply test to see whether `this` is bound before proceeding.

You can do it too:

```
function MyConstructor() {
  if (!this) return new MyConstructor();
  // stuff ...
}
```

Now calling `MyConstructor()` will behave exactly like `new MyConstructor()`.

Also, a constructor *can* return something. If it returns an object, then that's used instead of the implicitly-constructed object that `new` creates. Thus you could also implement a "new-is-optional" constructor another way:

```
function MyConstructor() {
  let object = this || Object.create(MyConstructor.prototype);
  // stuff ...
  return object;
}
```

So the `Number()` constructor takes a different tack. In most runtimes it may or may not actually be implemented as JavaScript, but if it were it might look something like this:

```
function Number(n) {
  if (this) {
    // invoked with "new"
    this.fantasyValueSetter(n); // cannot really do this
    return this;
  }
  return +n; // plain number primitive if not invoked with "new"
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Thank you for that clear example.